# ConcurrentDictionary - broken dictionary or bad code?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, concurrentdictionary

Alright, so I'm running into a strange little issue and frankly I'm out of ideas.  I wanted to throw this out there to see if I'm missing something that I've done wrong, or if ConcurrentDictionary isn't working correctly.  Here's the code:

(Cache is a class containing the static ConcurrentDictionary Keys)

```
var tmp = Cache.Keys.GetOrAdd(type,
                key =>
                {
                    var keys = context.GetKeys(key);
                    if (keys.Count() == 1)
                    {
                        return new KeyInfo
                            {
                                Name = keys.First().Name,
                                Info = key.GetInfo(keys.First().Name)
                            };
                    }

                    return null;
                });

            if (tmp == null)
                Cache.Keys.TryRemove(type, out tmp);

            return tmp;
```

The problem is that occasionally `tmp` is `null`, causing the `TryRemove` line to run, yet the `return null;` line above is never hit.  Since that `return null` is the only thing putting `null` into the dictionary and it never runs, how could `tmp` ever be `null`?

---

Including the Cache class (SetNames is not used by this code):

```
public class Cache
{
    public static ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Info> Keys = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Info>();
    public static ConcurrentDictionary<Type, string> SetNames = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, string>();
}
```

Comment: Maybe there is already a `null` value in the dictionary?

Comment: How many threads are running this code? It doesn't seem to be thread-safe.

Comment: @IlyaKogan - No, the dictionary is empty when it starts and never contains a null, even when the breakpoint inside `if (tmp == null)` is hit.

Comment: @oleksii It was my every intent for it to be thread safe.  Could you specify the areas you think will cause problems?

Comment: Are you sure that line is never hit?  The breakpoint is set explicitly in the lambda and not on the statement itself?

Comment: Also, can we see the Cache class?  Are we sure nothing in it alters the `ConcurrentDictionary`?

Comment: Is it possible that `context.GetKeys()` returns the same object as `Cache.Keys`?  That would complicate things somewhat.

Comment: @phoog It does not - `context.GetKeys()` returns a simple list, a new list for each call.

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare Unless it's broken, it's never hit.  I've included `Cache`

Comment: @MichaelTrotter correct me if I am wrong. ConcurrentDictionary is thread safe, but the method GetOrAdd takes in a delegate Func<TKey, TValue>. So if you have 2 threads that execute a delegate at the same time, as in the code, both threads would run this code concurrently with no synchronisation. This would be my guess.

Comment: @MichaelTrotter: Possible, but not likely.  I've used ConcurrentDictionary a lot and never run into an issue like this, so I think it more likely there's something with the usage.

Comment: @oleksii: you are correct, the call to the delegate may happen simultaneously for any given key, locking of the code inside of it (if desired) is the user's responsibility.  I believe that was a design decision so that the CD wouldn't be hampered by a long factory method unless explicitly desired by the user.

Comment: oleksii, that may happen, however I don't think it would cause any issue in this case.  It might foul things up in the context.GetKeys method, yes, but I can't see how it might result in nulls in this Cache.Keys dictionary.

Comment: @oleksii True, but I'm not sure how that would be a problem.  None of those threads are hitting `return null`, so while they may end up overriding each other on which instance of `KeyInfo` makes it into the dictionary, none of them could be putting `null` into it.

Comment: Tried replacing `return null` with `throw new Exception()` - none were thrown

Comment: Can you confirm that you are 100% sure that this code is what is actually running in your tests?  Throw an exception in a *normal* code path- like in the delegate before getting the keys list.  Make sure we are not chasing our tails.

Comment: The type returned by the factory is KeyInfo, the type stored is Info, is there a cast between them?

Comment: @JonHanna it wouldn't compile if there wasn't.

Comment: @ChrisShain Presumably no, but it could be a copy-paste error rather than a matter of the actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should have closed this a while ago but I completely forgot about it.  The example is not thread safe because of `TryRemove`, but that was only added for debugging purposes.  I ended up getting around the problem by rewriting it, so perhaps some of the comments about the code somehow being stale are correct.  The code no longer exists to confirm, however.

I'm chalking this one up to user error (my own of course).  Thanks for everyone's time!

Answer (score 3):

`tmp` can be null if you get anything other than a single item set back from `context.GetKeys(key)`.  In that case, `keys.Count() != 1`, and a null item will be inserted into `Cache.Keys` for the specified key (and returned from `GetOrAdd`, and assigned to `tmp`).

EDIT: Just thought of another possibility.  What datatype is the key?  Is it some kind of custom class?  It looks like it is.  If so, have you implemented `Equals` and `GetHashcode` properly?

Comment: but the OP states that the `return null` line is never executed, which, if correct, means that your scenario never occurs.

Comment: @phoog is correct - I also double checked the incoming parameters as well as `context.GetKeys(key)` and that case will not occur with this data.  I expect it to happen in the future, but that's not the problem.

Comment: Then the OP is mistaken :-)  Either the dictionary contains a null for the specified key, or the return null line is executed.  Now, from the variable names I am dubious about the call to GetOrAdd on the **Keys** member, but that's another story.

Comment: @ChrisShain I understand what you're saying, and I've been trying to find out which of those is the case.  The reason I created this post was because in every case neither of those are the problem, which doesn't make sense.  If `Cache.Keys` ever contains a `null` then the breakpoint on `return null` is broken.

Comment: @ChrisShain The key is a .net `Type` object

Comment: Type implements Hashcode and Equals properly, so that isn't the issue...  Can you put some logging in there rather than relying on the breakpoint?

Comment: @ChrisShain That would be more reliable - working on that now

Comment: Either return null is being hit in your value factory, or you are adding null to the dictionary somewhere else.
Try changing return null into throw new exception. The you can be absolutely sure you are not adding nulls.